# JQuery: How to get text using decimals in class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following are class names

```
<p class="question3.1">Question 3.1</p>
<p class="question3.10">Question 3.10</p>
<p class="question3.11">Question 3.11</p>
<p class="question3.12">Question 3.12</p>
```

I want to get value of text 3.1 in JQuery:

```
alert($("p[class*='question3.1']").text())
```

It returns text of all questions i.e

```
Question 3.1Question 3.10Question 3.11Question 3.12
```

But if i use following then it work fine.

```
alert($("p[class*='question3.10']").text())
```

How can i pick text of question3.1 only?

I could not refactor HTML.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e9w9fhyw/

Comment: Use ends with `$` selector, [`$("p[class$='question3.1']").text()`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/e9w9fhyw/1/)

Comment: Wow. Thanks it worked. Why this happens?

Comment: @Tushar IMO [`~=`](https://jsfiddle.net/e9w9fhyw/2/) would be better (the question* class name doesn't have to be the last one).

Comment: @fatherazrael https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: I have similar question 1.1 to question 1.10 and similarly 2.1 to 2.20 and 5.1 to 5.30 and so on

Comment: @pawel

Unable to understand difference between ~= and $=

Comment: @fatherazrael it's all clearly described in the MDN docs linked above. `$=` means "the attribute value ends with this string", and `~=` means "this exact word appers among the space separated words in the attribute value".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those classnames are insane.

You *can* select them, though. You have two choices:

1. A class selector that you escape the `.` in, and
2. The whitespace-separated attribute selector (`~=`)

#### Escaped class selector

The CSS class selector for the first one is

```
.question3\2e\31
```

`\2e` is the dot, and then because it happens that what follows the dot is a digit, which could be taken into the escape sequence, we use `\31` for the `1`.

To write that in a jQuery selector you have to escape the backslashes, so to get the first one, you'd use:

```
$(".question3\\2e\\31").text()
```

**Live Example:**

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  "The first one is: " + $(".question3\\2e\\31").text()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question3.1">Question 3.1</p>
<p class="question3.10">Question 3.10</p>
<p class="question3.11">Question 3.11</p>
<p class="question3.12">Question 3.12</p>
<hr>
```

#### Whitespace-separated attribute selector

The [whitespace-separated attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) `[att~="val"]`...

> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.

So:

```
$('[class~="question3.1"]').text()
```

**Live Example:**

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  "The first one is: " + $('[class~="question3.1"]').text()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="question3.1">Question 3.1</p>
<p class="question3.10">Question 3.10</p>
<p class="question3.11">Question 3.11</p>
<p class="question3.12">Question 3.12</p>
<hr>
```

Comment: It works with jQuery as is, without escaping anything (at least in the original attribute selector solution).

Comment: Isn't this overhead as i need to enter one replace also which replace . with \\2e\\3 . But thanks for this suggestion too.

Comment: @fatherazrael: What do you mean by "overhead"?

Comment: Like i pick question number dynamically : var qnumber = $(this).text().trim(); and i need to put $(this).text().trim().replace(".","\\2e\\3"). Something happen inside selector will be helpful.

Comment: @fatherazrael: The `~=` is probably what you want, then, but the overhead of converting to the escaped syntax is not something to worry about. The clarity is why I'd prefer `~=`.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to have a look at: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). So change it to something like this:

```
<p class="question" data-question="3.1">Question 3.1</p>
<p class="question" data-question="3.10">Question 3.10</p>
<p class="question" data-question="3.11">Question 3.11</p>
<p class="question" data-question="3.12">Question 3.12</p>
```

And then your jQuery would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('.question[data-question="3.10"]').html());
});
```

The above will print Question 3.10 in your console!

Comment: > *I could not refactor HTML.*